# wpf binding ObservableDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding, observable

I already read some post on stackoverflow but... I can't solve my problem.

Windows.xaml code

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBox x:Name="txt1" Margin="0,0,300,0" Text="{Binding Path=MyData[Code1], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txt2" Margin="0,0,300,0" Text="{Binding Path=MyData[Code2], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Content="Test" Click="Button_Click" Width="300" Margin="10"/>
</StackPanel>
```

My code-behind (usually I don't use code-behind, but in this way it's easier to show my problem)

```
        public ObservableDictionary<string, string> MyData { get; } = new ObservableDictionary<string, string>();

        public Window4() {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;

            MyData.Add("Code1", "Description 1");
            MyData.Add("Code2", "Description 2");
            MyData.Add("Code3", "Description 3");
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            MyData["Code1"] = "A new description here";
        }
```

So, I want to bind my observable collection MyData to textboxes. Well, when window started
textbox "txt1" has the correct value "Description 1"
textbox "txt2" has the correct value "Description 2"

Now, clicking on button "txt1" should show "A new description here"... but... nothing happens... Why?

If I put a breakpoint on button click, type a new value on "txt1", I click the button, my observable collection correctly contains the new value I typed...

Why textboxes binding works well only at startup? It's driving me crazy...

This is my ObservableDictionary class

```
    [DebuggerDisplay("Count={Count}")]
    public class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> :
        ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDictionary<TKey, TValue>,
        INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged {
        readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary;

        /// <summary>Event raised when the collection changes.</summary>
        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged = (sender, args) => { };

        /// <summary>Event raised when a property on the collection changes.</summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, args) => { };

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes an instance of the class.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableDictionary()
            : this(new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>()) {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes an instance of the class using another dictionary as 
        /// the key/value store.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary) {
            this.dictionary = dictionary;
        }

        void AddWithNotification(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) {
            AddWithNotification(item.Key, item.Value);
        }

        void AddWithNotification(TKey key, TValue value) {
            dictionary.Add(key, value);

            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add,
                new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value)));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Keys"));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Values"));
        }

        bool RemoveWithNotification(TKey key) {
            TValue value;
            if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value) && dictionary.Remove(key)) {
                CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove,
                    new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value)));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Keys"));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Values"));

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        void UpdateWithNotification(TKey key, TValue value) {
            TValue existing;
            if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out existing)) {
                dictionary[key] = value;

                CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace,
                    new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value),
                    new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, existing)));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Values"));
            } else {
                AddWithNotification(key, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows derived classes to raise custom property changed events.
        /// </summary>
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
            PropertyChanged(this, args);
        }

        #region IDictionary<TKey,TValue> Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds an element with the provided key and value to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The object to use as the key of the element to add.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The object to use as the value of the element to add.</param>
        public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) {
            AddWithNotification(key, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2" /> contains an element with the specified key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key to locate in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2" />.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2" /> contains an element with the key; otherwise, false.
        /// </returns>
        public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) {
            return dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets an <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" /> containing the keys of the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" /> containing the keys of the object that implements <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2" />.</returns>
        public ICollection<TKey> Keys {
            get { return dictionary.Keys; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the element with the specified key from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key of the element to remove.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if the element is successfully removed; otherwise, false.  This method also returns false if <paramref name="key" /> was not found in the original <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2" />.
        /// </returns>
        public bool Remove(TKey key) {
            return RemoveWithNotification(key);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value associated with the specified key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key whose value to get.</param>
        /// <param name="value">When this method returns, the value associated with the specified key, if the key is found; otherwise, the default value for the type of the <paramref name="value" /> parameter. This parameter is passed uninitialized.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if the object that implements <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2" /> contains an element with the specified key; otherwise, false.
        /// </returns>
        public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) {
            return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets an <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" /> containing the values in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" /> containing the values in the object that implements <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2" />.</returns>
        public ICollection<TValue> Values {
            get { return dictionary.Values; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the element with the specified key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public TValue this[TKey key] {
            get { return dictionary[key]; }
            set { UpdateWithNotification(key, value); }
        }

        #endregion

        #region ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) {
            AddWithNotification(item);
        }

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Clear() {
            ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)dictionary).Clear();

            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Keys"));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Values"));
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) {
            return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)dictionary).Contains(item);
        }

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex) {
            ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)dictionary).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        int ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Count {
            get { return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)dictionary).Count; }
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.IsReadOnly {
            get { return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)dictionary).IsReadOnly; }
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) {
            return RemoveWithNotification(item.Key);
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members

        IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator() {
            return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)dictionary).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
            return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)dictionary).GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: In button click, also doing             MyData.Remove("Code1");
            MyData.Add("Code1", "A new description here");       doesn't work...

Comment: I tried to add an event handler       MyData.CollectionChanged += MyData_CollectionChanged;   and the event raised correctly when I change the value in      MyData["Code1"] = "A new description here";

Comment: Is that dr wpf's observable dictionary? http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/

Comment: Woa... Andy. Thank you very much!!! The ObservableDictionary in DrWPF works correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Keys and Values are collections in which elements change, but the collections themselves are the same.
You create a PropertyChanged with these values, the binding checks that it is the same collection, and then pauses the update.

Create an empty PropertyChanged and then a full update of all values should occur.

Partial example:

```
    public static PropertyChangedEventArgs EmptyPropertyChangedEventArgs {get;}
         = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty);
    void AddWithNotification(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, value);

        CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add,
            new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value)));
        // PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        // PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Keys"));
        // PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Values"));
        PropertyChanged(this, EmptyPropertyChangedEventArgs);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how to use your example...